# Editing db files programmatically

Tags: android, sql

Is there a way to edit (to run SQL queries) db files (such as launcher.db), which are located on Android devices from Android application? The only way I know is running SQL queries from adb, but I think it's impossible to run such commands from android application.

Comment: if it is impossible to execute query from android application then what is the use of Sqlite ? How we are going to fetch the stored data ?

Comment: where is the data base located?  On the phone, or, on a remote server?  This is important to know.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to manipulate the DB, have you tried this little tool?

http://sourceforge.net/projects/sqlitebrowser/

I used it before and it suited my needs, although I have to admit that it was only a very small DB I was using